# How to transfer files from worker node to head node using ray in azureml

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, ray

attached is the simple script to use ray on AzureML. Here the remote function creates files for each size in the matrix in their respective worker nodes. Any suggestions on how to transfer the files to head node ? Thanks

```
import os
import sys
import ray
import time
from pathlib import Path
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from ray_on_aml.core import Ray_On_AML
import numpy as np


# Function to execute MATLAB script
@ray.remote
def run_script(size):
    value = np.square(size)
    np.savetxt(f"output_{size}.txt", value)
    return {"matrix_size": size}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # grab the arguments when the script is ran
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    sys.path.append(BASE_DIR.as_posix())

    ray_on_aml = Ray_On_AML()
    ray = ray_on_aml.getRay()

    if ray:  # in the headnode
        ray.init(address="auto")
        print("head node detected")
        print(ray.cluster_resources())
        start = time.time()

        mat_size = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

        script_handles = []
        for i in range(5):
            subset = mat_size[:2]
            mat_size = mat_size[2:]
            script_handles.extend([run_script.remote(size) for size in subset])
       
        # # Get and print the results
        results = ray.get(script_handles)

        end = time.time()
        dur = end - start
        print(f" tests took {dur} seconds")
        print("The current files in the directory are", os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
        # Shutdown Ray
        ray.shutdown()
    else:
         print("in worker node, do nothing")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how to transfer the files to head node ?

Use Azure Blob Storage, which provides a convenient and scalable way to store and retrieve files.

Firstly, Install the `azure-storage-blob` package - `pip install azure-storage-blob`

- After the files are created on the worker nodes, you can upload them to Azure Blob Storage.

**Code:**

```py
import os
import sys
import ray
import time
import numpy as np
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
from pathlib import Path
from ray_on_aml.core import Ray_On_AML

# Function to execute MATLAB script
@ray.remote
def run_script(size):
    value = np.square(size)
    np.savetxt(f"output_{size}.txt", value)
    return {"matrix_size": size}

# Your Azure Storage account connection string
connection_string = "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"
container_name = "output-files"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # grab the arguments when the script is ran
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    sys.path.append(BASE_DIR.as_posix())

    ray_on_aml = Ray_On_AML()
    ray = ray_on_aml.getRay()

    if ray:  # in the headnode
        ray.init(address="auto")
        print("head node detected")
        print(ray.cluster_resources())
        start = time.time()

        mat_size = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

        script_handles = []
        for i in range(5):
            subset = mat_size[:2]
            mat_size = mat_size[2:]
            script_handles.extend([run_script.remote(size) for size in subset])
       
        # Get and print the results
        results = ray.get(script_handles)

        end = time.time()
        dur = end - start
        print(f" tests took {dur} seconds")
        print("The current files in the directory are", os.listdir(os.getcwd()))

        # Upload files to Azure Blob Storage
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
        container_client.create_container()

        for size in mat_size:
            file_name = f"output_{size}.txt"
            with open(file_name, "rb") as data:
                container_client.upload_blob(name=file_name, data=data)

        # Retrieve files from Azure Blob Storage
        blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
        for blob in blob_list:
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
            file_name = blob.name
            with open(file_name, "wb") as download_file:
                download_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall())

        # Shutdown Ray
        ray.shutdown()
    else:
        print("in worker node, do nothing")
```

- After the Ray job completes, you can retrieve the files from the shared file system on the head node using the appropriate client library.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. But not very clear. The upload_blob function is appearing out of the ray job. Also we are not returning any file content from the remote function as well.

Comment: Firstly, you will need to ensure that each worker node saves its files locally. above current code already does this by creating files using `np.savetxt(f"output_{size}.txt", value)` within the run_script function. Now, within the Ray job, use Azure Blob Storage to upload these files from the worker nodes to a storage container.